# How to set the pen tool in photoshop to control one side anchor point in just a click

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, tools

I wanted to set the pen tool in photoshop to act like pen tool in illustrator where whenever I click again the last point the other side of the anchor point disappears.

[image]

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Hold down `alt` when you click the anchor point?

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/155752/359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally hate the pen tool in Photoshop, after becoming good with it in Illustrator.  If you do end up having to use it though, and if I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish correctly, then you'll want to use the `Convert Point Tool` to accomplish your task.

[image: tool]

With that tool selected, you can move the individual handles.  Say I have this shape below with the two handles stemming from the anchor point, fixed together as they normally would be.

[image: handles]

With the `Convert Point Tool` selected, simply click on the handle that you wish to move and move it.

[image: moved]