# Adding (or removing) a SINGLE bezier handle on an anchor point in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anchor-point, bezier-curve

I know how to use the **Convert Point tool** to [convert smooth points to corner points](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-paths.html#convert_between_smooth_points_and_corner_points) and vice versa, as shown below:

[image]

I also know how to use the Convert Point tool to 'break' the handles, so they can be adjusted independently. However, what I can't seem to figure out is how to convert an anchor point into a ***corner point with just one handle***, so that one adjoining segment has a curve but the other is straight (i.e. no handle).

Every example I've come across demonstrates conversions between two handles to zero handles, and vice versa.

**SPECS:** Adobe Photoshop 2022 on Mac

Comment: You can also do the opposite just drag an existing handle so it coincides with the point. Mathematically ist just a 0 length handle.

Comment: @joojaa - yea but it doesn't get rid of the handle, and doing that is imprecise and annoying. It's like trying to create a smooth point by manually lining up two broken handles - you could technically do it, but why would you want to?

Comment: well it snaps to the point if you have point snapping on and then dissapears. Not entirely same since its way more precise. Also by the way the handle you get when you drag a wymmetrical handle is not what you really want you want to have the handles length modulated by span length, yet the engine does not do that. So if you really wanted to be precise you would numerically build snap points and put the handles there

Comment: "it snaps to the point if you have point snapping on and then disappears" - I couldn't get this working, even with snapping on, and the handle def didn't disappear. If I click-drag the direct selection tool on that point it will drag the handle that's on top of it. "you really want to have the handles length modulated by span length" - I don't follow this, can you explain?

Comment: @joojaa FYI Adobe Community Pro [confirms](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/photoshop-cs6-how-can-i-delete-a-handle-when-using-pen-tool/m-p/12714579#M619418) that using the shortcuts is better than dragging handle to point.

Comment: yeah well i use illustrator mostly snapping there is wastly better than in photoshop. Anyway the curvature of a bezier is based on the overall length of the bezier curve segment. So in reality youd want the tangents to be different lengths based on how long the individual segments on the sides are or make the points uniformly spaced or uniformly spaced in domain of function. While this isnt such a big deal in 2D it should still be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to do this, you must select the **Convert Point tool** *from the TOOLBAR* (you CANNOT do this by pressing ALT/OPTION while using the pen tool)!

[image]

## To create a corner point with just ONE LEADING HANDLE:

1. Convert the anchor point to a corner point with zero handles (if not one already), by clicking the point once with the **Convert Point tool**.
2. Next, click and drag with the **Convert Point tool** while pressing ALT/OPTION.

[Video example](https://youtu.be/L283DNLccAw?t=14)

## To create a corner point with just ONE TRAILING HANDLE:

1. Convert the anchor point to a smooth point with two handles (if not one already), by clicking and dragging on the point with the **Convert Point tool**.
2. Next, click once on the point with the  **Convert Point tool** while pressing ALT/OPTION.

[Video example](https://youtu.be/L283DNLccAw?t=23)

---

(All credit for solution and video go to [Nika](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/photoshop-cs6-how-can-i-delete-a-handle-when-using-pen-tool/m-p/11173643#M335996), whoever you are ;))